# What are the applications of Euler's formula?

Tags: complex-analysis

I have just seen the proof for Euler's theorem, and i have to say, i am pretty amazed! But I still don't understand why it is useful, or intuitive, at all. Idk where to even begin. I have seen the wiki page, but it is either convoluted or seemingly useless.

Thanks

Comment: A derivation of n-angle (double, triple, ...) identities is a nice quick result $(\cos x + i\sin x)^n=\cos (nx) + i\sin (nx)$; expand the left.

Comment: Depends on what you mean by `applications'. Do you mean outside math? It is used in so many contexts that it is like asking for the applications of matrix multiplication.

Comment: If you “don't understand why it is useful”, try picturing electrical engineering without it. Or any other branch of science, which studies $($sinusoidal$)$ signals of any kind $($acoustic, visual, magnetic, etc$)$.

Comment: To do that, I would have to know how it is practically applied in any of those fields (which I don't, which is the reason why I posted the question in the first place! :)

Answer (score 2):

If we call Euler's formula $\exp(i\theta)=\cos(\theta) + i \sin(\theta)$ then one of the more esoteric reasons to use Euler's formula is to represent rotations easier.  Rather than representing a rotation as a $2\times 2$ matrix multiplication with a two element vector, we can represent it as a multiplication of a complex exponential $\exp(i\theta)$ with a complex number.  This can simplify equations involving rotations drastically.

This was vital in understanding the [MRI signal equation](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wrlQxlo0uT4&list=UU5zRsg5XEpKe2AWFyi0mvrw) and is thoroughly used in the continual development of MRI today.

Answer (score 1):

You can write:

$\sin x = \operatorname{Im}(e^{ix})$, $\cos x = \operatorname{Re}(e^{ix})$.

which is often useful. More than that, consider:

$e^{i\theta} = \cos \theta + i \sin \theta$

$e^{-i\theta} = \cos \theta - i\sin \theta$

Where the second equation comes from $\cos$ being even and $\sin$ being odd.

Subtract or add the equations together and you can express $\sin$ and $\cos$ completely in terms of the exponential function! And once you have those you can do the other 4 trig functions.